# ClassNotFoundException when using dynamic classloader

Tags: java

It's a project downloaded from Web and I just changed the path to find the class which I want to make it load dynamically.Here are the codes in which I try to load the class on runtime.But I got a ClassNotFoundException eventually:

```
private static IExample newInstanceWithThrows() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
URLClassLoader tmp =
  new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {getClassPath()}) {
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name)
    throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if ("example.Example".equals(name)
        || "example.Leak".equals(name))
      return findClass(name);
    return super.loadClass(name);
  }
};

return (IExample) tmp.loadClass("example.Example")
  .newInstance();


}

  private static URL getClassPath() {
    String dir = "/Users/longtuan/develop/rjc2011/classes/";
    try {
      //return new URL(dir);
        File path = new File(dir);
        return path.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

And the path to class example.Example is:
*/Users/longtuan/develop/java/rjc2011/classes/example*

And the run command I used is:
*java -classpath ./bin example.Main*

Current directory is:
*/Users/longtuan/develop/java/rjc2011*

All the things of current directory are like this:
[image]

Example is the directory in which I put all the java files.I place the compiled class file in  directory bin except the class example.Example which is put in classes lonely.

Above are all the informations I can give, thanks for any help.

Comment: `/Users/longtuan/develop/java/rjc2011` is a different path than `/Users/longtuan/develop/rjc2011/classes/`. One includes a `java/` subdirectory the other does not. Btw. the entire subclass of URLClassLoader does not make any sense. URLClassLoader already does the job. Your `loadClass` method…looks very weird.

Comment: @Holger:Directory "rjc2011" is like a project name, and subdirectory "classes" is the place in which I put all the classes excluding the class example.Example.I know what you mean but I can't find anything wrong with it.Can you explain more to me.Thanks a million.

Comment: I already said that “java/” is missing in one of your paths. It’s not about “rjc2011/” and not about “classes/”. It’s the “java/” part. There’s nothing more to say about.